# Особенности JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть простая функция:

```
var y = 0;
function foo (x) {
    if(x) {
        console.log(y);
    } else {
        var y = 2;
        console.log(y);
    }
}
foo(true);
```

Может кто доступно пояснить по какой причине мы получаем `undefined` в случае когда `x` `true`, почему он не берет `y` из глобальной области?

Comment: не запутывайте код двумя `var y` - и будет понятнее что куда. Скорее всего интерпретатор сначало ищет локальные переменные, добавляет их в стек, а потом выполняет функцию.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я не запутываю. Мне интересно почему интерпретатор так поступает?